# ScrollViewer will not stop scrolling after calling ScrollToBottom()

Tags: .net, wpf, scroll, scrollviewer

I have a view in my application that contains an `ItemsControl` within a `ScrollViewer` to display log messages. The collection of strings that are the messages is an `ObservableCollection<string>` within my viewmodel.

When a new message is added, the `ScrollViewer` needs to scroll to the bottom of the list, depending on whether a checkbox is checked or not. I'd like to handle this completely in the view. I found a decent solution ([here](http://www.wpfmentor.com/2008/11/notification-when-items-are-added-or.html)). The checkbox is checked by default initially.

I'm seeing strange behavior, though:

- Before any messages are added, if I uncheck the checkbox, and add messages to the list, the list does not scroll (correct behavior).
- If I leave the checkbox checked, and add messages, the list scrolls (correct behavior).
- If I add a few message to the list, then uncheck the box, then add more to the list, the list still scrolls (**incorrect behavior**).

I've distilled it down to a very simple WPF application that demonstrates the problem, which is below.

What is causing this and how do I fix it?

The XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="229" Width="551">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <CheckBox Grid.Row="0" Content="Autoscroll?" Name="AutoscrollCheckBox"  IsChecked="True" />
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Add a message" Name="AddMessageButton" Click="AddMessageButton_Click" />
        <ScrollViewer Name="MessagesScrollViewer" Grid.Row="2">
            <ItemsControl Name="MessagesList" ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged {

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        ((INotifyCollectionChanged)MessagesList.Items).CollectionChanged += Messages_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void Messages_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
        Console.WriteLine((bool)AutoscrollCheckBox.IsChecked);
        if (AutoscrollCheckBox.IsChecked.HasValue && (bool)AutoscrollCheckBox.IsChecked && (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add))
            MessagesScrollViewer.ScrollToBottom();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> m_Messages = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> Messages {
        get { return m_Messages; }
        set { m_Messages = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Messages"); }
    }

    private int _msgNumber = 0;

    private void AddMessageButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        Messages.Add(String.Format("Message #{0}", _msgNumber++));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name) {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Comment: Scrolling to new items is default behaviour. You would have to stop this if IsChecked is False instead of calling ScrollToBottom if IsChecked is True. (+1 for providing a running sample)

Comment: That's not correct. Comment out the last line of the constructor that subscribes to the event and no scrolling will occur.

Comment: Oh, your right. I saw a changing scrollbar but it was because of new items. Sorry.

Comment: I have no explanation but a workaround: Add `else MessagesScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(MessagesScrollViewer.VerticalOffset);` in Messages_CollectionChanged. Seems this stops this weird behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the explanation from [ScrollViewer Source Code](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/Dotnetfx_Win7_3@5@1/Dotnetfx_Win7_3@5@1/3@5@1/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/Orcas/NetFXw7/wpf/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ScrollViewer@cs/2/ScrollViewer@cs):

If you call `ScrollToBottom` a `Double.PositiveInfinity` value will be set as `VerticalOffset`.

```
/// <summary>
/// Vertically scroll to the end of the content.
/// </summary>
public void ScrollToBottom()
{
    EnqueueCommand(Commands.SetVerticalOffset, Double.PositiveInfinity, null);
}
```

After adding a new item `ScrollViewer` updates the view with the last `VerticalOffset` which is still `PositiveInfinity` meaning it scrolls again to the end. With

```
var verticalOffset = MessagesScrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
MessagesScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(verticalOffset)‌​;
```

`ScrollViewer` sets the real `VerticalOffset` and all will be okay.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to dig into this!

Comment: One suggestion in addition. Now we know the relation maybe you could edit question title and tags to help others with this only ScrollViewer problem to find the answer.